# How can I call multiple APIs that are depending to each other's data, each response data must be used on the following API call?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm, coroutinescope

//From Kotlin code (Compose View), using CoroutineScope

```
scope.launch {
    viewModel.getDataOne(key)
    viewModel.data_one.collect{ one ->
        when(one){
            is DataState.Success->{
                viewModel.getDataTwo(one.data.value1, one.data.value2)
                viewModel.data_two.collect{ two ->
                    when(two){
                        is DataState.Success->{
                            viewModel.getDataThree(two.data.valueID, two.data.valueName)
                            viewModel.data_three.collect{ three ->
                                when(three){
                                    is DataState.Success->{
                                        //Continue with your calls
                                        /**
                                         * But then, this doesn't look clean beacuse of the nested api calls.
                                         * So is the a clean way to write this calls on your Views?
                                         */
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// Function from ViewModel

```
fun getDataOne(key:String){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getDataOne(key = key).collect{
            valueDataState.tryEmit(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to write a clean Code than having this long nested calls, if there's a proper way or a cleaner way to write that.
Thanks in advance .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be flattened out. You have a lot of nested collect calls, which can be flattened using flat mapping. You need to do this anyway if any of those inner flows are SharedFlows/StateFlows/from repositories. Those kinds of flows are infinite, so if you do a nested collect, it will be stuck on the first value of the outer flow forever. The "latest" part of `flatMapLatest` gives it an opportunity to restart the inner flow if the outer flow has a new value.

```
scope.launch {
    viewModel.getDataOne(key)
    viewModel.data_one
        .filter { it is DataState.Success }
        .flatMapLatest { one ->
            viewModel.getDataTwo(one.data.value1, one.data.value2)
            viewModel.data_two
        }
        .filter { it is DataState.Success }
        .flatMapLatest { two ->
            viewModel.getDataThree(two.data.valueID, two.data.valueName)
            viewModel.data_three
        }
        .filter { it is DataState.Success }
        .collect { three ->
            //...
        }
}
```

But to me it looks like this should all be in done in the view model and exposed as a single flow for the UI to consume. This stuff is working with the data, not displaying it.

---

The following is something else you can do to make it fit conventions better and make the code easier to read.

Instead of the `getDataOne()` function, I would change it to a `dataOneKey` property, because that's all this function really does. It sets the key that's used as the dependency of the `data_one` flow. Functions with `get` at the start usually return the thing they are describing. This is kind of a universal OOP convention, although in Kotlin there are properties, so you usually only see getter functions if they are suspend functions. So, here's how I would change the view model. I have to make some guesses here because I don't really know what the other flows in your view model are currently designed as. You could convert each of your `get` functions something like this:

```
private val dataOneKeyFlow = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
var dataOneKey: String?
    get() = dataOneKeyFlow.value
    set(value) { dataOneKeyFlow.value = value }
val valueDataState = dataOneKeyFlow
    .flatMapLatest { key -> if (key == null) emptyFlow() else repository.getDataOne(key) }
    .shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L), replay = 1)
```

Then on the other end it would look like:

```
scope.launch {
    viewModel.dataOneKey = key
    viewModel.data_one
        .filter { it is DataState.Success }
        //...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative feedback, please brighten me from the little confusion I have. I understand your response and it looks clean, so I will use this line off code from my viewModel ```private val dataOneKeyFlow = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
var dataOneKey: String?
    get() = dataOneKeyFlow.value
    set(value) { dataOneKeyFlow.value = value }
val valueDataState = dataOneKeyFlow
    .flatMapLatest { key -> if (key == null) emptyFlow() else repository.getDataOne(key) }
    .shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L), replay = 1)```

Comment: But what if i have multiple params that i need to pass to my repository function like: ```repository.getDataOne(key,value,idNumber,boolean)```, Please if you can simplify that for me @Tenfour04

Comment: You could create an immutable data class with those parameters and make a flow of that.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and helping me out, I really appreciate it a lot..... Thank you @Tenfour04